# Angular 4 ошибка компиляции error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: typescript, angular4

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> "ERROR in src/app/data.service.ts(11,25): error TS1005: ',' expected."

Вот код data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()

export class DataService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

getData(){

return this.http.get(url:'http://angulara/public/api/data')

}

}
```

Как устранить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

> ```
> return this.http.get(url:'http://angulara/public/api/data')
> ```

используйте:

```
return this.http.get('http://angulara/public/api/data')
```

Comment: @Kromster, рррррррррррррррр

Comment: Вы считаете с пояснениями стало хуже? Или хотите немного больше развернуть свой ответ, объяснить почему так (т.е. дать человеку удочку и научить его ловить рыбу, а не дать ему готовую) ?

Comment: @Kromster, просто по-моему, добавленный текст практически ничего полезного к ответу не добавляет.

Comment: Для постороннего человека - добавляет. То что один фрагмент в желто-серой рамке, а второй в просто серой практически ни о чем не говорит. Вы просто привели 2 строки кода .. а так хотя бы есть сопроводительная инфа. Ответ ваш - хотите - откатывайте, или лучше дополните ..